# Problems saving Images to NSManagedObjects after adding func controllerWillChangeContent

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

need your support I've been struggling with this for days. I'll appreciate any help.

how The App Works :

I have a Pin NSManagedObject and an Photo NSManagedObject, they have one-to-many relationship, i.e., one Pin has many Photos.

I have 2 screens, in the first one the user adds Pin in Apple Map on the view context and they get added and retrieved without problems.

Now, in the second screen, the App retrieve images based on the Pin location selected in the first screen, then display the images in a Collection View. The images are first retrieved from flickr,
then saved in the DB.

(save and retrieve images on a background context Using FetchedResultsController)

i want to add a new Feature that allow  The user to Delete the Photo from Collection View And Delete Photo from  db

before i add this Feature the App was working great (i can insert images in MY DB)

but

after i add this Feature every time i try to insert photo in My DB the
App crush

the Error Message :

> [UICollectionView] Invalid update: invalid number of items in section
> 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of items contained in
> that section before the update (250), plus or minus the number of
> items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted)
> and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that
> section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). - will perform reloadData.
> UICollectionView instance: <UICollectionView: 0x7f99c3bc6000; frame =
> (0 282; 414 518); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM;
> gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002ac80f0>; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x6000024a8900>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414,
> 14063.999999999998}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f99cb402bf0>; dataSource:
> <VirtualTourist.PhotoAlbumViewController: 0x7f99cb4167d0>>;
> currentUpdate: [UICollectionViewUpdate - 0x7f99cb4a6570:
> old:<UICollectionViewData: 0x600001d00700> new<UICollectionViewData:
> 0x600001d74a80> items:<(

my code that handle the Delete in UICollection View

```
extension PhotoAlbumViewController
{
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        insertIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        deleteIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        updateIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        switch type{

        case .insert:
            print("Insert an item newIndexPath : \(newIndexPath!)")
            self.insertIndexPaths.append(newIndexPath!)

        case .delete:
            print("Delete an Item")
            deleteIndexPaths.append(indexPath!)

        case .update:
            print("Update an item")
            updateIndexPaths.append(indexPath!)

        case .move:
            print("move")
            
        default:
            break

        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {


        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            for indexPath in self.insertIndexPaths {

                print("Inserting FetchedObjects at: \(indexPath)")
                self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])

            }

            for indexPath in self.deleteIndexPaths {
                self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
            }

            for indexPath in self.updateIndexPaths{
                self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            }

        }, completion: {complete in
            print("complete")

        })
    }
}
```

this is My App repo :
https://github.com/Saad-Altwaim/IOS/blob/master/VirtualTourist2_2.zip

Comment: Welcome to SO. We would need some more info. Please [edit] your question and add a [example] showing any relevant code. See also [ask].

Comment: Based on the "imgur" image, the `In file included from...` is the "note" portion of an error or warning.  Without seeing the actual error/warning it's attached to there is not enough information to give any meaningful response.  The "notes" on errors usually give further information about the error based on other parts of the code base than where the error was detected.  For example, a duplicate variable will have a note for the the location where the other declaration for the variable that conflicts with the one generating the error.

Comment: All that can surmised from the image is that the error, whatever it is, is happening in some header file that's included from `filename.m`.  But beyond that, more info about the error is needed to know what is wrong.